# How to get response with JWT in Golang

Tags: go, jwt

I'm trying get the response from an API that uses JSON Web token, I need use the header : {
  Authorization: "Bearer token"
}
But I would like to keep the timeout of the http.Client that I'm using. How could I do it?

```
    var myClient = &http.Client{Timeout: 10 * time.Second}

func getJson(url string, target interface{}) error {
    r, err := myClient.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer r.Body.Close()

    return json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(target)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[net/http.Request](https://godoc.org/net/http#Request) has a `Header` field that you can directly edit, but this means you can't use the shortcut `client.Get` method.  Something more like:

```
req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, url, nil)
if err != nil {
        return err
}
req.Header = map[string][]string{
        "Authorization": {fmt.Sprintf("Bearer %s", jwt)},
}
r, err := myClient.Do(req)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this,

```
func getJson(url string, target interface{}) error {
req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, url, nil)
if nil != err {
    return err
}
r, err := myClient.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
defer r.Body.Close()
return json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(target)
```

}

Alternatively , you could also use context to control the request timeout

```
func getJsonWithContext(url string, target interface{}) error {
req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, url, nil)
if nil != err {
    return err
}
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Second*1)
defer cancel()
reqWithContext := req.WithContext(ctx)
r, err := myClient.Do(reqWithContext)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
defer r.Body.Close()
return json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(target)
```

}